# How to force page/element refresh on button click in Apex?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a select list which is sourced from a SQL query. When I hit a button, a process is called which deletes the currently selected item from the table. However, even though the item is, in fact, removed from the actual database, it still shows up in the select list. Any way that I can force the refresh of the select list? Or at least a full page refresh after the button is clicked?

Comment: What sort of process does your button do: an on-submit process, or is it an ajax callback? In case of an on-submit process: doesn't this cause your page to reload? If it does, what is the source of your item and is it configured to be 'always replaced'? More info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force refresh of a select list using a dynamic action (assuming you are using Apex 4.0 or later - you didn't specify).

Create a dynamic action that is triggered by the click of the button, and whose action is Refresh and target is the select list item.

If you are already using a dynamic action to call the process then you can make this refresh the second True Action in the same dynamic action.  If you are currently using Javascript to perform the processing then you could have an issue in the order of events; it may be necessary to modify your page to use a dynamic action instead.

If you are on Apex 3.2 or earlier then you would have to either submit the page after performing the processing (call doSubmit in javascript), or write Javascript to refresh the contents of the select list - not trivial.